# Как избежать повторения части условий в конструкции CASE в MySQL?

Tags: mysql, case

Только начал знакомство с MySQL. Поясните почему я могу сделать так

```
SELECT `Дата заключения` AS Подписан,
    CASE
        WHEN month(`Дата заключения`) BETWEEN 3 AND 5 THEN 'Весна'
        WHEN month(`Дата заключения`) BETWEEN 6 AND 8 THEN 'Лето'
        WHEN month(`Дата заключения`) BETWEEN 9 AND 11 THEN 'Осень'
        ELSE 'Зима'
    END AS Сезон
    FROM договор
    ORDER BY Подписан DESC;
```

Но не могу сделать так

```
SELECT `Дата заключения` AS Подписан,
    CASE month(`Дата заключения`)
        WHEN BETWEEN 3 AND 5 THEN 'Весна'
        WHEN BETWEEN 6 AND 8 THEN 'Лето'
        WHEN BETWEEN 9 AND 11 THEN 'Осень'
        ELSE 'Зима'
    END AS Сезон
    FROM договор
    ORDER BY Подписан DESC;
```

То есть вопрос в том, как написать вычисление месяца один раз.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По стандарту SQL. Сокращенный CASE допускает только сравнение с конкретными значениями и только на равенство.

Answer (score 2):

> как написать вычисление месяца один раз

Можете, конечно, попробовать использовать переменную:

```
SELECT `Дата заключения` AS Подписан,
    CASE
        WHEN (@month:=month(`Дата заключения`)) BETWEEN 3 AND 5 THEN 'Весна'
        WHEN @month BETWEEN 6 AND 8 THEN 'Лето'
        WHEN @month BETWEEN 9 AND 11 THEN 'Осень'
        ELSE 'Зима'
    END AS Сезон
FROM договор
ORDER BY Подписан DESC;
```

Но, во-первых, профит копеечный, фиг заметишь, во-вторых, сервер не дурак, и скорее всего сам выполнит вычисление только один раз (он же формализует выражения).

Хотя я бы вообще сделал так:

```
SELECT `Дата заключения` AS Подписан,
    ELT(1+(month(`Дата заключения`) DIV 3), 'Зима', 'Весна', 'Лето', 'Осень', 'Зима') AS Сезон
FROM договор
ORDER BY Подписан DESC;
```

Comment: По заданию надо использовать CASE каким либо образом. Поэтому ваш вариант короче, но не для этого случая.

Comment: @Owl *По заданию* Так это учебное задание, оказывается, а не реальная задача? *но не для этого случая* Чем вариант с UDV не устроил?

Comment: Да, учебное. Суть в использовании CASE каким либо образом.